# Trigger an Elementor Popup (log in popup) on an external APP

Tags: wordpress, elementor

Help NEEDED [dev question]
So. I'm loading WP on an external app

**My goal** : trigger an Elementor Popup (log in popup) when the user is not connected.
I did everything (wp-load, condition if logged or no) and it works.
**My issue :** Elementor Styles & Js are not loading so my popup is not properly working.

Any ideas ?
[image]